# Spinner con LiveData y Room

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner, android-room

Soy nuevo con la programación en Android y me ha surgido un problema. Tengo un Spinner que muestra una lista de Strings que vienen de la base de datos (uso Room) y me gustaría que cuando se añade un registro a la tabla de donde salen los datos se actualice dicho Spinner.
En la query del Dao ya he hecho que se devuelva una lista LiveData:

```
LiveData<List<String>> getAllNames();
```

Me falta la parte de la actualización. Tengo entendido que tengo que añadir un observador pero no sé cómo. No uso viewModel ni Recycler View (aún no sé que son) y el siguiente código es lo que tengo actualmente para rellenar el Spinner.

Un saludo

```
    spinner = findViewById(R.id.mainSpinner);
    List<String> marcas = AppDatabase.getDatabase(this).dbMarcaDao().getAllNames();
    marcas.add(0,"Todas");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, marcas);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**-----------EDIT-------------**
Gracias a la guia de Jorgesys he conseguido dar con la solución, aunque han surgido varios detalles:
- Puesto para obtener el Dao de Room se necesita el contexto, mi nueva clase "MyViewModel" se debe extender de *AndroidViewModel* ya que *ViewModel* no tiene contexto.
- No he usado el *MutableLiveData*, sino *LiveData* por todo.
- No es necesario "inicializar" el spinnner, de eso se encarga la nueva clase.

Mi código quedaría así:
**MainActivity**:

```
spinner = findViewById(R.id.mainSpinner);
marcas = new ArrayList<String>();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, marcas);        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
MyViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
model.getMarcas().observe(this, new Observer<List<String>>() {
  @Override
  public void onChanged(List<String> nuevas_marcas) {
     marcas.clear();
     for (String term : nuevas_marcas) {
       marcas.add(term);
     }
     marcas.add(0,"Todas");
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
});
```

"**MyViewModel**"

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private LiveData<List<String>> nombresMarcas;
    public MyViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public LiveData<List<String>> getMarcas() {
        if (nombresMarcas == null) { ;
            cargaMarcas();
        }
        return nombresMarcas;
    }

    private void cargaMarcas() {
        nombresMarcas = AppDatabase.getDatabase(getApplication().getApplicationContext()).dbMarcaDao().getAllNames();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad antes de añadir el observador debes crear una clase que extienda de ViewModel, en la cual obtendrás una lista

```
private MutableLiveData<List<String>> namesList;
```

y donde debes implementar el método para obtener los nombres, por ejemplo:

```
LiveData<List<String>> getAllNames() {

    if (namesList == null) {
        //Instancia lista
        namesList = new MutableLiveData<>();
        //Carga usuarios.
        loadUsers();
    }
    return usersList;
}

private void loadNames() {

   //Obtiene Nombres.

}
```

ahora con esta clase puedes definir tu observer para que identifique cambios:

```
 NamesViewModel model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(NamesViewModel.class);

        model.getAllNames().observe(this, new Observer<List<String>>() {
            @Override


            public void onChanged(List<String> usersList) {

                // Actualiza datos
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                spinner.notifyDataSetChanged(); 

            }
        });
```

Muy importante revisar:

[Descripción general de ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

[Descripción general de LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)